# Trigger for displaying tray icon

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon, system-tray

I am currently using cinnamon on ubuntu 14.04. I have an email client that is showing a little icon in the notification tray every time I receive an email.

I want to know if there is a way of capturing the process that is causing that behaviour and do something else. (e.g. my laptop has a small led attached to it and I would like to make it start blinking).

If I can't find the process it would be also very useful if I can check what items I have in the tray bar and trigger a custom script when I find the icon I am looking for.

I want to do this programmatically so I can make it part of a script.

[image: This is how the tray looks.]

Pretty picture of my tray bar above so you know what I am referring to.

Comment: What is the email client? Are you using 14.04 or 10.04? You have said one in tags and one is the question body.

Comment: Thanks @Tim it's 14.04. The email client is just an example. I'd like to be able to do this for other software too in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the way each program does this would be slightly different. Let me have a look.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584774/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-active-icons-present-in-the-system-tray may get an answer at some point. If it does, it may help you.